# Continue execution even if one step fails in cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, assertion

I want to continue executing my scenarios even if some fail in between in the cucumber report it should show it as a failure but should not stop the execution.

I tried using soft assertion class and using this

```
 SoftAssertion sa = new SoftAssertion();
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Sytem.out.println("pAASED")
            } else {
                sa.fail("this is the failure");
            }
```

but suppose I have two scenarios and for the first one the response is not 200 it is going to else block and failing the scenario

```
java.lang.AssertionError: this is the failure
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
```

it is not even going for the second scenario. Can someone help how can I achieve the expected result(i.e it should continue the execution irrespective of one getting failed)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two different things.

1. Error Code As Response
2. Exception

As per definition of exception from [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html#:%7E:text=Definition%3A%20An%20exception%20is%20an,off%20to%20the%20runtime%20system.&text=This%20block%20of%20code%20is%20called%20an%20exception%20handler.) :

> An exception is an event, which occurs during the execution of a
> program, that disrupts the normal flow of the program's instructions.

In this way exception is totally different from normal flow of execution. So if you want to proceed even in case of exception you need to use the [concept of exception handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm). As below:

```
try {
    response = yourMethodCall();
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e)
}
```

In above sample code:

1. Replace `yourMethodCall()` with actual method call.
2. Catch proper minimum exception. (In your case it should be `AssertionError`)
3. Consider logging of your exception for better debugging, as in the code. For that create log object.

Comment: @notescew Thank you for the detailed solution. But using try catch block it is just simply catching the exception and not failing it. In the report i see it as passed one
~~~
try { if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    try {
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.asString());
name = jsonObj.getString("name");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
     }
    }
   } catch (AssertionError e) {
    e.getMessage();
   }
~~~I used this code but even there is an issue it shows passed. I want that it should continue execution but in the report should show failure